# Set minimum height to scroll bar on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, scrollbar

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to set a minimum height to the scroll bar.

I have files I open often and know where certain data is within those files.

I'm lazy and I don't want to scroll through (via wheel or keys) some of these files when I can easily use the scroll bar to get to a particular part of the file instantly.

Comment: Why not just CTRL-F for your "certain data"?

Comment: @Clayton Too lazy. It seems that the scroll bar has a fixed minimum that I consider too small. It makes it more difficult for point-and-click operations. I'd rather it stay relatively medium sized and just have the sensitivity of the scrolling become adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify registry value to adjust scrollbars

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics

Change the string value named " ScrollHeight". Set its value using the following formula:-15*desired width in pixels

For example, to set the scrollbar width to 18px, set the ScrollWidth value to -15*18 = -270

Also, you can edit the value ScrollWidth using the same formula to adjust the width

After change, restart computer.

Besides, some third-party can do the same thing.

Sources:

How to change the size of scrollbars in Windows 10

https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-change-the-size-of-scrollbars-in-windows-10/